# What is the word after '여러분' in this audio recording?

Tags: vocabulary

I would like some help to understand what is the very first word said in this audio:

https://open.spotify.com/episode/3doXEJA6gSj8sAd3fduGHb?si=sAJAOzqWSUOZTRNmYoVqzA

The word is followed by 여러분, so it seems to be a greeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**하바라기** 여러분, 안녕하세요."

It's a fandom name. It seems to appear on [an official transcription](https://podcasts.apple.com/ua/podcast/asmr-%EC%86%8D%EB%8B%A5%EC%86%8D%EB%8B%A5-%EB%A7%90-%EB%A7%8E%EC%9D%80-%EA%B3%A0%EB%8D%B0%EA%B8%B0/id1523787210?i=1000534515129).

Historically from [해바라기](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=85358&lang=eng), (anything)바라기 is often used to form names for fandoms or hobby clubs.

---

I had no idea what kind of audio I was about to hear, thanks for the surprise .

Comment: If your question was resolved, accept this post as the answer!

Comment: It surely was resolved. Sorry for the delay. I didn't know I had the option to accept an answer. Thank you one more time!